# Getting value of a thread variable from outside

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say i have a thread running like this:

```
private boolean working = true;

@Override public void run() {
   working = true;
   // do something
   working = false;
   ....
}
```

and in my main Thread i'm constantly putting out the state of working with

```
while(threadClassObject.isWorking()) {
    System.out.println(threadClassObject.isWorking());
}
```

would this work? I tried this example and it seems to work. But is there a way that this could crash? What e.g. happens if the thread is in the process of changing working while at the exact same time the mainThread tries to read it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ans to your question is that it might be working but the above code is a risky code and can break any day. Try making `working` `volatile` like

```
private volatile boolean working = true;
```

`What e.g. happens if the thread is in the process of changing working while at the exact same time the mainThread tries to read it?`

Assignment operation is an atomic operation. So if you have single cpu, two threads can never collide while accessing the variable. If you have more than one cpu, two threads can collide while accessing the variable. For both cases, `volatile` will make sure that the value is visible to other threads.

NOTE: `volatile` is good in your situation but if you have more complex data to share across thread [try looking into this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Edit:

Adding the comment also part of the soln. to make it more clear.

Basically bcoz of optimization at cpu level, values changed my one thread might not be visible to another. A good example is cpu cache bcoz optimization the values are never reflected in ram where the other thread might be reading. Volatile tells that this variable's value can be changed outside the scope of current thread so no such optimization is done...

Comment: Ok thanks for the answers guys, have now changed it to volatile. What exactly would happen if they collide? Cause i have now made 2 endless loops, one in the thread that constanstly changes the working variable and one in the main Thread that constantly checks it and nothing happens.

Comment: Basically bcoz of optimization at cpu level, values changed my one thread might not be visible to another. A good example is cpu cache bcoz optimization the values are never reflected in ram where the other thread might be reading. Volatile tells that this variable's value can be changed outside the scope of current thread so no such optimization is done...

Answer (score 3):

You might also want look into doing something with your "runaway" while loop in your main thread:

The current implementation will keep spinning, not leaving much CPU time left for your threads executing `run()` (or anyone else in the system, for that matter).

Comment: To elaborate, `Thread.sleep` and `Thread.yield` are both simple ways to prevent this from happening. A more robust solution would be to restructure the program to be event-driven, or something.

Comment: Thanks, i only made the loop that way to test it, so i constantly access the thread variable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either use synchronization or AtomicBoolean in order for that to be thread safe.  What you have in your code will seem to work, but it's possible that when you check the boolean, it won't be the correct value, so you'll see unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary to lock primitive types like a boolean. If 'working' was an object, then you'd need to use *synchronized* blocks.

Comment: If it is not `volatile` then `isValue()` called in main thread calling may not see the changed value.

Comment: There's no danger of observing a boolean in a partial state, but you can still get in trouble: there's no guarantee that the main thread will _ever_ see a write made in the child thread unless the program establishes a happens-before relationship with the write and the read via synchronization of some kind. This is independent of whether working is an object or a primitive.